# Does DotSpatial Reproject work for non-global to global projections?

Tags: c#, dotspatial

As a small part of a project i need to convert shapefile geometry from OSGB1936 (EPSG:27700) to WGS1984/Pseudo (EPSG:3857) and output as wkt. I found the DotSpatial library which looked promising and shoehorned this;

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        var pathin = "G:\\SearchArea_region.shp";
        var pathout = "G:\\wkt.txt";

        using (var fs = FeatureSet.Open(pathin))                
        {
            var writer = new WktWriter();
            var numRows = fs.NumRows();
            for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
            {
                var shape = fs.GetShape(i, true);
                var geometry = shape.ToGeometry();

                double[] xyArray = new double[geometry.Coordinates.Count() * 2]; //START Reprojection
                double[] zArray = new double[1];
                int counterX = 0;
                int counterY = 1;
                foreach (var coordinate in geometry.Coordinates)
                {
                    xyArray[counterX] = coordinate.X;
                    xyArray[counterY] = coordinate.Y;
                    counterX = counterX + 2;
                    counterY = counterY + 2;
                }
                var EPSG27700 = new ProjectionInfo();
                var EPSG3857 = new ProjectionInfo();
                EPSG27700 = KnownCoordinateSystems.Geographic.Europe.OSGB1936; //OSBNG
                EPSG3857 = KnownCoordinateSystems.Geographic.World.WGS1984; //Pseudo Merc
                Reproject.ReprojectPoints(xyArray, zArray, EPSG27700, EPSG3857, 0, (xyArray.Length / 2));
                counterX = 0;
                counterY = 1;
                foreach (var coordinate in geometry.Coordinates)
                {
                    coordinate.X = xyArray[counterX];
                    coordinate.Y = xyArray[counterY];

                    counterX = counterX + 2;
                    counterY = counterY + 2;
                }
                geometry.GeometryChanged(); //END

                var wkt = writer.Write((Geometry)geometry);
                MessageBox.Show(wkt);
                System.IO.File.WriteAllText(pathout, wkt);
            }

        }

    }
```

From a question elsewhere on this site. However, this outputs only "infinity/infinity" coords or does no reprojection at all. I have tried to find DotSpatial tutorials but links back just seem to go back to the archived site landing page with no accessible information.

Either, the code is rubbish but i don't know enough to fix it or the re-project is failing because OSGB isn't a global system.

Comment: Have you tried GDAL for C#? It sounds like you were looking for a spatial lib and crashed into dotSpatial and are only using that because you hit it first... Sorry I can't help with dotSpatial, I could never get it to work properly either.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you don't have the proper projections. Looking at the code, the OSGB maps to EPSG 4277 (lat long). Try using

```
EPSG27700 = ProjectionInfo.FromEpsgCode(27700)
```

The second one is not EPSG 3857 (projected) but 4326 (lat long)

```
EPSG3857  = ProjectionInfo.FromEpsgCode(3857)
```

Comment: I'm getting a 'type name doesn't exist' error. I'm on version 1.9 of DotSpatial has FromEpsgCode been depreciated?

Comment: @benj I am using v2.0